# Sync Folder between Linux and Mac

Tags: linux, macos, mac, sync

I have an always-on Linux box in the cloud. On that machine, there are some files I would like to (bidirectionally!) sync to my local machine - my iMac (running 10.8).

The files I would like to sync are in a folder, and would probably by in the 1-2MB range for everything. I have root access to the machine.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not use a software like Dropbox or SugarSync?

Comment: @Undo There is a joke comment ridiculing "the cloud" and there is a serious suggestion/answer with `rsync`. The joke is not necessarily a good fit on this site, but frankly, I think popular terms "web 2.0" and "the cloud" are ambiguous at best and serve no practical purpose. Anyway, comments are not a place for subjective opinions and I should probably respect that in the future...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A widely known and robust program to perform this task is known as *rsync(1)*. There are ample examples on the net, and also on superuser.com of how to use it. If still in doubt after exhausting these sources of examples and the one provided in this answer, consult the manual page under category User commands (1) by issuing `man 1 rsync` in the terminal.

e.g.

```
mortal@home$ rsync -auv /mnt/umbrella/ zeus@rainycloud.com:~/umbrella/ # push
mortal@home$ rsync -auv zeus@rainycloud.com:~/umbrella/ /mnt/umbrella/ # pull
```